# PayPal doesn't return an authorization id

Tags: python, python-3.x, paypal

This is my first time with paypal and I need some help to finish payment integration. I've already tried to contact the paypal support but with no success. Here is my question and I really hope to get some help.

Something very strange grinds my gears and I cannot find why this do that. It's about the user authorization, and specially about paypal json responses. I'm using python sdk but that doesn't matter in this case. Here is my input.

```
paypalrestsdk.configure({
    'mode': 'sandbox',
'client_id': 'XXX',
'client_secret': 'XXX'
})
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
    "intent": "authorize",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://mysite/success",
        "cancel_url": "http://mysite/cancel"
    },
    "transactions": [ {
        "amount": {
            "total": price,
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "description": title
    }]
})
```

And everything is ОК, except that I doesn't receive an Authorization ID. Here is what I receive as response:

```
{
    'redirect_urls':{
    'cancel_url':'http://glamfame.com:8000/cancel',
    'return_url':'http://glamfame.com:8000/success'
},
'update_time':'2014-04-08T13:54:22Z',
'state':'created',
'transactions':[
{
    'amount':{
        'currency':'USD',
        'total':'123.00',
        'details':{
            'subtotal':'123.00'
        }
    },
    'description':'fawfwa',
    'related_resources':[{
        'authorization':{
            'valid_until':'2014-05-07T13:54:22Z',
            'update_time':'2014-04-08T13:54:22Z',
            'parent_payment':'PAY-54Y91315F8620142DKNB77DQ',
            'create_time':'2014-04-08T13:54:22Z',
            'links':[{
                'method':'GET',
                [link removed]
                'rel':'parent_payment'
            }]
        }
    }]
}],
'payer':{
    'payer_info':{
        'shipping_address':{
        }
    },
'payment_method':'paypal'
},
'id':'PAY-54Y91315F8620142DKNB77DQ',
'intent':'authorize',
'create_time':'2014-04-08T13:54:22Z',
'links':[{ POST, GET, REDIRECT methods with links
    }]
```

And below is what I supposed to receive according their documentation.

```
{
    "id": "2DC87612EK520411B",
    "create_time": "2013-06-25T21:39:15Z",
    "update_time": "2013-06-25T21:39:17Z",
    "state": "authorized",
    "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
        "subtotal": "7.47"
    }
 },
"parent_payment": "PAY-36246664YD343335CKHFA4AY",
"valid_until": "2013-07-24T21:39:15Z",
"links": [
{
    "href": [link removed]
    "rel": "self",
    "method": "GET"
},
{
    "href": [link removed]
    "rel": "capture",
    "method": "POST"
},
{
    "href": [link removed]
    "rel": "void",
    "method": "POST"
},
{
    "href": [link removed]
    "rel": "parent_payment",
    "method": "GET"
}]
}
```

As you maybe already noticed, in the paypal response doesn't contain authorization id and void, and capture link. Can you please help me to find out the reason for this. Thank you in advance.

Best Regards,
Georgi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the REST API documentation: With PayPal payments authorizations, PayPal initially provides HATEOAS links that are specific to PayPal payments including an approval_url and execute link. First [get payment approval](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/#get-payment-approval) and [execute the payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/#execute-the-payment) as you normally would do for a PayPal payment. Once you successfully execute on the payment authorization, PayPal responds with a new set of HATEOAS links, including a capture link that you use to capture the payment.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It was really simple and I really don't know how I have missed this. Now everything work exactly as expected.